# Add c# user project property to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

What is the correct way to add user project property to a c# Visual Studio 2022 project (the one that gets referenced like this:

```
$(propName)
```

).

I need to create the user property to use it during build process.
So far I have found the way to add the property to the *project*`.csproj`
file by adding an xml `PropertyGroup` tag:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BackEndDir>BackEnd</BackEndDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Preferably I wouldn't like to touch `.csproj` file.

Comment: There is no such thing as Property Manager in my system. Remember I am using c# project and Visual Studio 2022. Could you please point me out where is `Project Manager` in the menu?

Comment: Where else (other than the csproj file) do you think it could go?  You can pick up environment variables, but that can get difficult (since your developers and your build box both have to have the same variables set).

Comment: Is there GUI interface to do that